# Complete examples of program correctness proofs

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, programming-languages, proof-techniques, correctness-proof

Does anyone have any complete example of a proof of program correctness? I'm talking about something that includes the usual predicate, base case, inductive hypothesis, and inductive step. But also important is the loop invariant, and termination. I'm just not sure what the proper format for something like this is.

The only things I've been able to find are powerpoint slides from random schools, but they are for teaching purposes, and all over the place. I'm looking for something from start to finish, easy to follow, and formatted nicely that it can be submitted academically.

I wish to understand what a program proof looks like when (if) it is used for real, rather than as a proof sketch for a toy example in the classroom.

Comment: There are loooots of them in [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms). What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Something online and free? :)

Comment: You want to submit something academically, ask other people to do it for you, and don't want to visit a library? Huh.

Comment: I don't want anyone to do it for me.

Comment: There are multiple free, online algorithms textbooks.  Take a look at them to see if any of them meet your eneds.

Comment: How big a program? What kind of proof?

Comment: If you are still interested in proofs of program correctness as you describes, we are offering and edX course starting April 11, 2017 called LAFF-On Programming for correctness that answers all of your questions. https://www.edx.org/course/laff-programming-correctness-utaustinx-ut-p4c-14-01x

Comment: Are you after formal proofs (e.g. for purposes of formal verification), or after semi-formal arguments like the ones that can be found in textbooks and papers in the area of algorithmics?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Can you provide a list of books for both ? I tried getting the hang of semi formal argument but they seem a bit too hand wavy with any specific structure. Do you think knowing the formalism behind it makes it easier to follow ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with textbooks or monographs in the area.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Are you familiar with any book that gives semi-formal argument but explains how they obtained it. For example, instead of just saying that the loop-invariant is ... it actually says how the loop invariant was obtained and explains how proving an ASSERTION about an invariant is the same as proving the correctness of a COMMAND.

Comment: Unfortunately not. You can perhaps try looking into formal verification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find a collection of proof techniques illustrated with poofs of small programs in the following paper:

[Inductive Methods for Proving Properties of Programs](http://www.nesssoftware.com/nesssoftware/doc/stanford/cacm.pdf), Manna, Ness, Vuillemin, CACM 16-8, August 1973.

It is made available on the web by one of the authors. It is also the first paper I ever read on the subject, and I remember enjoying it.

But I would expect the literature, on and off the web, refereed papers, textbooks and other sources. to include a considerable number of such proofs, considering that today people are working on the proofs of real program (such as [compilers](http://compcert.inria.fr/doc/)), with the help of mechanized proof systems.

OF course, you are aware that there is no such thing as correctness in an absolute sense. Correctness is defined only with respect to some specification, i.e. to some predicate in a logic that can also express the meaning of programs
(or whatever part of it is relevant).

Of course, there are different ways of defining the semantics of a program. So one might expect to have proof techniques that vary accordingly.

Comment: I do have a textbook that explains these things. It's similar to the one you showed, but both don't have an example proof from start to finish without random notes everywhere. I guess it's like you say, there is nothing formal. Also, I've been told that the people who write these proofs are programmers. So I'm going to assume they show it to their bosses, then scrap it after the program has been written.

Comment: @fossdeep Actually, proving (properties of) programs in real life is quite difficult, and probably beyond the competence of most programmers. It is also nothing that their boss wants to read. People who make these proofs are either algorithm designers (you do not publish an algorithm without some kind of proof), or proof specialist for complex programs. Both are mathematicians. For actual programs, proofs are conducted on proof assistant systems, which do most of the error checking. It is more a matter of process, than a final document with a written proof on it. Only the computer sees that.

Comment: @fossdeep In other words, it is exactly the opposite of scraps of paper. For algorithms you ave formal academic papers. For complex programs you may have proof assistants, very systematic and using no paper at all. I am not saying that proof assistant are not used for algorithms. This is only to give you a quick sketch of situations that can be encountered. It is real science ... you want proofs to give you assurance, hence you want a process that can be trusted.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: @fossdeep Among the major motivations in industry, you have safety of life
critical devices (vehicles, or medical equipment for example), and also reliability of cryptographic system.
They also do a lot of program proving in space industry because silly
bugs just cost to much money. So the cost of proving correctness is
worth paying.