# What is the general class of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

> You have an array of `N` numbers. Find all the numbers that occur more
>   `N/5` times in the array.

This can be obviously done in `O(n log n)` time and `O(1)` space, or `O(n)` time and `O(n)` space, but the catch is that it can be done in O(n) time and `O(1)` space.

After hours of thinking I found the solution, which is [absolutely the same as described here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43771/27369) (and it is not hard to extend it for `M` times).

---

My question is: **does this problem belongs to some general class of algorithms? and what kind of similar problems are there?** Like dynamic programming, greedy or recursion (these are clearly wrong classes)?

I was looking at the [streaming algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_algorithm), but it does not look this is the case.

Comment: I don't know the answer. However, why do you want to know the general class it falls into? In addition, "similar problems" is a broad term. Anyway, you can find a formal study of this problem in [this paper: Finding Repeated Elements@1982 (including a lower bound proof)](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/6345/82-505.pdf?sequence=1).

Comment: @hengxin this problem looks different in comparison to problems I solved previously. It was pretty hard to me and I assume this is the basic problem of this particular type. I would like to learn more about these types of problems